# makefile: implicit rules: same target different prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following makefile:

```
all: DIR/0/a.txt DIR/1/b.txt DIR/2/c.txt DIR/3/abc.txt

DIR/%/abc.txt: DIR/%/def.xtx # rule #1
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    touch $@

DIR/%.txt: # rule #2
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    touch $@

DIR/%.xtx:
    touch $@
```

I want to generate `DIR/%/def.xtx` whenever `DIR/%/abc.txt` is generated; otherwise generate only `DIR/%.txt`.

Using the makefile above with GNU Make 3.81 however, only `DIR/3/abc.txt` gets generated and `DIR/%/def.xtx` is not generated.

Following the "Implicit rule search algorithm" in the GNU make user manual we get:

> (1) Split t into a directory part, called d, and the rest, called n. For example, if t is ‘src/foo.o’, then d is ‘src/’ and n is ‘foo.o’.

For `DIR/3/abc.txt`, `d = DIR/3` and `n = abc.txt`.

> (2) Make a list of all the pattern rules one of whose targets matches t or n. If the target pattern contains a slash, it is matched against t; otherwise, against n.

Rules #1 and #2 match.

> (3) If any rule in that list is not a match-anything rule, then remove all nonterminal match-anything rules from the list.

NOT SURE: no rule is removed from the list.

> (4) Remove from the list all rules with no recipe.

No rule is removed.

> (5) For each pattern rule in the list:
>
> (5.a) Find the stem s, which is the nonempty part of t or n matched by the ‘%’ in the target pattern.

For rule #1, `s = 3`.
For rule #2, `s = 3/abc`

> (5.b) Compute the prerequisite names by substituting s for ‘%’; if the target pattern does not contain a slash, append d to the front of each prerequisite name.

For rule #1, it becomes: `DIR/3/abc.txt: DIR/3/def.xtx`
Rule #2 has no prerequisites.

> (5.c) Test whether all the prerequisites exist or ought to exist. (If a file name is mentioned in the makefile as a target or as an explicit prerequisite, then we say it ought to exist.)

NOT SURE: `DIR/3/def.xtx` is mentioned by the rule `DIR/%.xtx:`.

After this long long long explanation, my opinion is that I am probably wrong in (5.c).

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think `%` will ever match something with a `/` in it. Thus, assuming the above is the entirety of your `Makefile`, you don't have any rule that will match `DIR/3/def.txt` and `make` should complain about "don't know how to build DIR/3/def.txt" or something along those lines.

Comment: It [%] does match things with `/`; otherwise `DIR/0/a.txt`, `DIR/1/b.txt` and `DIR/2/c` would not get touched; but they do.

Comment: Learned something new... it does seem to work. So, perhaps `DIR/3/def.xtx` doesn't get created because the third rule lacks the `mkdir` part? Since it's a prerequisite for `DIR/3/abc.txt` it needs to be built first, before the directory exists, so the `mkdir` in rule 1 won't happen before it tries to run rule 3.

Comment: Yes, that's an error but, make doesn't look at the recipes to find which ones it has to execute. If it worked touch would at least complain that the directory didn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match),

> A rule whose prerequisites actually exist or are mentioned always
>   takes priority over a rule with prerequisites that must be made by
>   chaining other implicit rules.

Your rule #1 requires chaining, your rule #2 has no prerequisites, so Make will choose #2 over #1 when trying to build `DIR/3/abc.txt`.

**EDIT:**

If you can stand having a list of directories:

```
DIRS := DIR/0 DIR/1 DIR/2 DIR/3
```

then you can do it with a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
all: DIR/0/a.txt DIR/1/b.txt DIR/2/c.txt DIR/3/abc.txt

ABC_TXT := $(addsuffix /abc.txt, $(DIRS))

$(ABC_TXT): DIR/%/abc.txt : DIR/%/def.xtx

DIR/%.txt:
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    touch $@

DIR/%.xtx:
    touch $@
```

(And it avoids duplication of the `.txt` rule too!)

Comment: That answers the question why rule #2 is chosen over rule #1 but, how could I circumvent this behaviour?!

Comment: We can explicitly make the prerequisites in the recipe (i.e., `make DIR/$*/def.xtx`) but that would be very inefficiently. Is there another way?!

Comment: Thanks a lot! That will do... at least for now. :)

Comment: The only problem with our solution really is the need to specify the list of directories. To circumvent that I've done the following: assign the prerequisites of all to a variable (i.e., ALL); then instead of `$(ABC_TXT): ...`, I've put `${filter DIR/%/abc.txt, $(ALL)}: DIR/%/abc.txt: DIR/%/def.xtx`.The trick here is the use of static pattern rules. Thanks a lot.